# Does uniformly boundedness implies boundedness of the union of images?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose:

1. $X$ is a compact space
2. $(Y, d)$ is a metric space
3. $ \mathcal{F} \subseteq C(X, Y) $ is a collection of continuous maps
4. $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e. there exists a number $M$ such that $ d(f(x), g(x)) \leq M $ for any $x \in X$ and $ f, g \in \mathcal{F} $. This is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal{F}$ is a bounded subset in $C(X, Y)$ under the sup metric.

**Question:**

Can we say that the union of images
$$ \mathcal{F}(X) = \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(X) = \{ f(x) : x \in X, f \in \mathcal{F} \} $$
is a bounded subset in $(Y, d)$?

To prove the boundedness of $ \mathcal{F}(X) $, we need to find a number $M'$ such that $ d(f(x), g(y)) \leq M' $ for any $x, y \in X$ and $ f, g \in \mathcal{F} $. This involves one more variable $y \in X$ than the uniformly boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $h \in \mathcal F$. Since $h$ is a continuous function on  a compact space it is bounded. Now $d(f(x),g(y))\leq d(f(x),h(x))+d(h(x),h(y))+d(h(y),g(y))$.